# Android: How to handle different physical tablets with same reported dpi?

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I hope I'm just being silly here.

For an app I'm trying to create 2 seperate layouts to scale the text nicely on two different physical devices, without having to generate a lot of conditionals in my code.
The two specific devices I'm having trouble with are:

Samsung Galaxy TabPro 
8.4" Tablet
1600x2560 px (Real) | 800x1255 DP | 800dp | 320dpi | 2.0 density | 1600x2560 px (Normal)

Samsung Nexus 10
10.1" Tablet
2560x1600 px (Real) | 1280x727 DP | 800dp | 320dpi | 2.0 density | 2560x1504 px (Normal)

How do I differentiate between these two devices in the layouts folder? They have the same dpi group, same density modifier, same dp group, same resolution, same everything. Except that one is 2 inches bigger than the other.

EDIT:
To add information about the exact issue (why I want to differentiate). Text with certain textsize SP shows up bigger on the 10" tablet compared to the 8" one. So much bigger in fact that the text becomes unsigthly. (As if you turned on Accessibility options without actually having them on)

Comment: Given that they have the same resolution and DPI, why do you need to differentiate them? Is it possible you are using an absolute layout somewhere? If you can use relative layouts / grid layouts / linear layouts, perhaps the problem will go away?

Comment: Reason is that (I assumed) due to the physical differences in screensize, the actual text gets scaled differently. On the Nexus 10 text looks twice as big compared to the TabPro, which is quite unsightly.

EDIT:
Also, all Layouts are either Linear or Relative. No absolute layouts were used.

Comment: How are you setting the font size? Are you using scale-independent pixels ("sp") for the fonts?

Comment: Yes, all text elements use sp for the textsize property. (But since a specific sp amount looks different from device to device, I'm using seperate layout folders containing custom sp values for phone-sized devices and tablets, so that the app has nicely sized text on all devices.)

Comment: @Michael I have the feeling that it actually may be related to the fact that the programmatically obtained DP/DPI/density/resolution values need not correspond to the actual physical dimensions of the device. As far as I've read there's nothing to do about that though.

Comment: I see. So, the difference in font size on these different devices may be by design. If you want to make the font size explicit, you can change to a unit that doesn't vary by device (though this may have implications for accessibility).

Answer (score 0):

You may do some manual calculation and inflate the layout manually if its really required.

here is how,

based on [DisplayMetrics](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/DisplayMetrics.html)

**xdpi**    The exact physical pixels per inch of the screen in the X dimension.

**ydpi**    The exact physical pixels per inch of the screen in the Y dimension.

**heightPixels**    The absolute height of the display in pixels.

**widthPixels**    The absolute width of the display in pixels.

**here is the rough code**

```
heightInInches = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().heightPixels 
/ getResources().getDisplayMetrics().xdpi;

widthInInches = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels 
/getResources().getDisplayMetrics().ydpi;

// formula for finding the diagonal of triangle
diagonalScreenSize = Math.sqrt((heightInInches*heightInInches) 
+ (widthInInches*widthInInches));
```